# Angular 4 POST call to php API fails, but GET request work and POST requests work from Postman

Tags: php, postman, angular-http

I have an Angular 5 application which connects to an PHP API, everything worked ok when testing in local environment (Ubuntu 16.04, Apache2 2.4.18, PHP 7.2.2) but when I deployed the project in my school server (Uubuntu, Apache2 2.4.27, PHP 7.1.11), GET requests are ok but POST requests are turned into OPTIONS requests and Angular displays the error.

> ERROR Object { _body: error, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "",
>   headers: {…}, type: 3, url: null }
>
> Request from origin has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin
>   Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
>   present on the requested resource.

I have alredy tested the API with Postman and everything works.

Here is the code of the DataService

```
constructor(public http:Http) {
  this.url = 'http://10.50.67.83/usuario1/Autozone/';
  this.headers = new Headers();
  this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
}

postRequisition(client:string, cart:Selected[]) {
  let data:Data;
  data = {client: client, cart: cart};

  return this.http.post(
    this.url + 'api/requisitions/create.php',
    JSON.stringify(data),
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: this.headers
  }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

I have added the ContentType header beacause I'm posting a JSON.

These are the headers included in the php file.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Accept: application/json;");
```